# How can I display an IPLImage stream on Qt interface using OpenGL for rendering?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opencv, iplimage

What is the best way to integrate and display an IplImage into a Qt GUI? Can this be done using OpenGL? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am answering my own question here.
I have been working with OpenCV since a year now and many times I have had to write code that opens a video file and streams it.
Lately, I have been using Qt to provide the high level gui and I came up with a solution to display IplImages on a Qt GUI using OpenGL(which I spent a lot of time struggling with but succeeded finally). Although, OpenCV can be built with Qt highgui support, I was keen in learning a bit of OpenGL and using it in my application.
I thought it would be helpful for people who need a basic framework for running videos for their applications.
This basic framework can be used in a wide range of applications like video content analysis, face recognition, pattern recognition and more. In the broader sense, this is basically a video player without audio support. So if you want you can add audio support and make this a video player. It will play almost all formats as opencv uses ffmpeg to play videos. I have created a C++ library for the same which I use quite extensively:

The main classes are:

```
QVideo : The main widget, providing functionality to open a video/rtsp stream and play it  
QIplImage: The core display widget. It's a QGLWidget which renders an IplImage
BackgroundWorker: This is a thread which runs in the background to retrieve images
from the stream. It is mandatory to run the frame grabber in a background thread,
otherwise it interferes with the GUI thread. All the image processing can be done in 
this thread
```

The source code is provided so you can modify it to your needs.
Once the library is installed, you can use it in your qt application like so:

```
//Create an object
QVideo* video=new QVideo("Name",);
//set geometry (optional)
setCentralWidget(video);
```

To build the library, you will need qt and opencv(with ffmpeg support) installed.
The library gets installed in /usr/lib or /usr/lib64 based on the architecture.
The include files get installed in /usr/local/include
Of course, all this can be changed in the project file if needed.
To install, just unzip the package, and run qmake, make and sudo make install.
Note: The project is configured for unix and would need to be changed for windows builds. Drop me a message for more information.